# What is meant by 'corresponds to'?

Tags: phrase-meaning, usage

In this text it says that a every natural number 'corresponds to' a quantity of distinct objects in a set.

I understand theres some mathematical theory here, but ignoring that, what does this sentence mean? That every number *is* a quantity of distinct objects, or for every number there is a quantity of distinct objects that we can associate with it (whether either is correct is not important), the meaning is what interests me.

I've seen 'corresponds to' used for both of these, is it simply implied by the context? I'm leaning towards the second but I am unsure?

Comment: A number is a word (e.g. 'three') or a symbol (e.g. '3') that _represents_ a quantity. The number is not the quantity. Your second suggestion is the correct one.

Comment: The number expressed as 'two', '2', or 'II' corresponds to the quantity of arms, hands, legs, eyes, or ears that you (hopefully) have, and 'ten', '10' or 'X' corresponds to the quantity of toes or fingers likewise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"correspond to" implies that there are two groups or lists, and a thing from one group matches with a thing from the other. For numbers, the number one corresponds to a group containing a single item, the number two corresponds to a group containing a pair of items, the number three corresponds to a group containing a trio of items, and so on.

Or one might say, "In many US weddings, each groomsman corresponds to a bridesmaid".

Or one might say "each key corresponds to a lock"

"Matches" gives a good idea of this sense of "correspond  -- there are other, quite different senses.

In modern mathematics, the idea of "one to one correspondence", setting up matching lists of things, is a basic and vital concept. It is now common to describe numbers as corresponding to groups with that number of elements.